# List View Sort By date Colomn

Tags: c#

I am New To C#,and i Have C# List View .I want to sort my listview by date oder using List view date colomn.this is the my list view.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyhb5.png)

i want sort this by the date oder.i found the some code on the internet but its give the some error.this is the my ItemComparer.cs class code

this is my listview colmn click event code

```
 ItemComparer sorter = listViewSample.ListViewItemSorter as ItemComparer;

        if (sorter == null)
        {
            sorter = new ItemComparer(e.Column);
            sorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
            listViewSample.ListViewItemSorter = sorter;
        }
        // if clicked column is already the column that is being sorted
        if (e.Column == sorter.Column)
        {
            // Reverse the current sort direction
            if (sorter.Order == SortOrder.Ascending)
                sorter.Order = SortOrder.Descending;
            else
                sorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else
        {
            // Set the column number that is to be sorted; default to ascending.
            sorter.Column = e.Column;
            sorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        listViewSample.Sort();
```

when i run the system it give me the error like this

> Error 644 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder' to 'System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

please any one know fix thiss error tell me how to fix it step by step

Comment: Try appending System.Forms. before you write SortOrder

Comment: using System.Windows.Forms; alrady Added.

Comment: Have you also included System.Data.SqlClient via using? Because then you need to write System.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending instead of just SortOrder.Ascending because otherwise the compiler won't know if you mean the class SortOrder from the Forms namespace or the SqlClient namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the your help.

Comment: Did it work for you?